# Recursive function call in Fold: $RecursionLimit issue

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, recursion

I'm trying to generate a list of all local complements of a graph $G$. A local graph complement $G\star v$ for $v\in V$ is defined as taking the neighbourhood of the vertex $v$, and flipping the existence of any edge within that neighbourhood.

I have the following Mathematica code.

```
LocalComplement[g_Graph,v_]:=LocalComplement[g,v]=With[{
        h=VertexDelete[NeighborhoodGraph[g,v],v]
    },
    GraphUnion[GraphDifference[g,h],GraphComplement[h]]
]
AllLocalComplements[g_Graph]:=AllLocalComplements[g]=AllLocalComplements[g,{g}]
AllLocalComplements[g_Graph,list_List,excludedVertices_List:{}]:=AllLocalComplements[g,Sort@list,Sort@excludedVertices]=Fold[AllLocalComplements[g,#1,#2]&,list,Complement[VertexList@g,excludedVertices]]
AllLocalComplements[g_Graph,list_List,v_]:=With[{
        lcg=LocalComplement[g,v]
    },
    If[
        MemberQ[list,gg_/;IsomorphicGraphQ[lcg,gg]],
        list,
        AllLocalComplements[lcg,list~Join~{lcg},{v}]
    ]
]
```

The algorithm is correct; however, starting at $n>6$ vertices (depends a bit on the graph, but definitely for $n=9$) there is a `$RecursionLimit=1024 exceeded` error cropping up. I suspect this is because of the `Fold[AllLocalComplements...`-call, which is highly recursive.

My questions:

1. Can MM somehow optimize this using tail recursion? And if not, is there a way of writing this in a MM-esque way? I know I can do it with `For`-loops etc. but that wouldn't be as pretty.
2. Can you give me advice on how to improve performance of the code?

Thanks a lot!

~ JB